# Xodus - Restore Environment / directory from Backup

Tags: java, xodus

This is how we backup Xodus:

```
PersistentEntityStore store = manager.getPersistentEntityStore(xodusRoot, appId);
final File backupFile = CompressBackupUtil.backup(store, new File(store.getLocation(), "backups"), null, true);
```

Using this ZIP file what is the safest way to restore the backup on a "production" or "live" server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible option is to unzip backup file and open a new `PersistentEntityStore`. You can keep open current instance of `PersistentEntityStore` until the backup is unzipped to a new location. Then you can open a new instance of `PersistentEntityStore` above the new location and switch atomically database load to the new instance.